# How to show the total hours using Time span

Tags: c#

I have a Scenario where I calculated two different hours and show the total calculated value in a cell.The below code working fine for HH:MM format.Sometimes the total calculated hours would be HHH:MM format.Its throwing error in that scenario.For example its working fine for 22:00(HH:MM) but not for 120:00(HHH:MM).Can anyone help me to sort this out

```
        TimeSpan Hoursspent, Calculatedhours;
        if (dtReport.Columns.Contains("Hours Spent"))
        {                
            foreach (DataRow row in dtReport.Rows)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Hours Spent"].ToString()))
                {
                    string temp2 = (row["Hours Spent"]).ToString();
                    Hoursspent = TimeSpan.Parse(temp2);
                    Calculatedhours = Calculatedhours + Hoursspent;
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: If its a fixed format, split on the `:` and the result is (pseudo) `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(hhh * 60 + mm)`. Wouldn't it be better to avoid strings altogether (in db and in code, use total seconds/minutes as integer or base10 decimal)?

Comment: `HHH` is no longer part of a datetime format. This is expected to be expressed in days, not multiples of 24 hours. There are other ways to achieve this, but they would require pre-processing the string and breaking it down into its core constituents, converting everything separately. It would be considerably easier if you were able to simply change your input file to use an integer format instead of a string format.. Are you able to change the input file's format?